# An orthogonal matrix which sends a vector to other vector with same length.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, orthogonal-matrices

I know that For every to vectors $u,v\in \mathbb R^n$ where $|u|=|v|$ there exists an orthogonal matrix $A$ such that, $Au=v$. I have a problem so construct this matrix. is there any method to construct this matrix?

Comment: did you check the proof of the result?

Comment: @Magnusseen Unfortunately I didn't found any proof about it. I just saw it in many books.

Comment: For example (is not unique), you can construct the simmetry $s$ such that $s(u)=v$. For this, consider a hyperplane $V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ orthogonal to $u-v$ that goes through the point $(u+v)/2$ and a basis of them: $\mathcal{B}=\{v_1,...,v_{n-1}\}$.
Then, $A$ is the matrix of $f$, such that $f(V)=Id_V=V$ and $f(u)=v$.

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo What is $f$ here?

Comment: @GhD $f$ is defined as $f(w)=w$ for all $w\in V$ and $f(u)=v$ (it is ok because $\mathcal{B}\cup u$ is a orthogonal basis).

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo sorry, why $u$ is not in $V$?

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo also do you know definition of orthogonal matrix? $A$ is orthogonal if $AA^T=A^TA=I$.

Comment: @GhD No. $V$ is the hyperplane equidistant of $u$ and $v$

Comment: @GhD equivalently, $A$ can be the matrix of an orthogonal transformation $f$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know Gram-Schmidt? If so, complete $u$ to an orthogonal basis $\mathcal{B}_1$ and do the same to $v$ (let's call its o.b. $\mathcal{B}_2$), and take the linear map which sends one to the other.

In more detail,  note that if $\Vert u\Vert=0$ the result is trivial. If not, complete $u$ to any basis $\{u,e_2,e_3,\cdots,e_n\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and do the same for $v$: $\{v,f_2,f_3,\cdots,f_n\}$. Apply Gram-Schmidt to both, yielding orthonormal bases
$$\mathcal{B}_1=\{\widetilde{u},\widetilde{e_2},\widetilde{e_3},\cdots, \widetilde{e_n}\}$$
and
$$\mathcal{B}_2=\{\widetilde{v},\widetilde{f_2},\widetilde{f_3},\cdots, \widetilde{f_n}\},$$
where $\widetilde{u}=\frac{u}{\Vert u\Vert}$ and $\widetilde{v}=\frac{v}{\Vert v\Vert}$. Consider the linear transformation $A$ which sends the elements of $\mathcal{B}_1$ to $\mathcal{B}_2$ "orderly" (i.e., $\widetilde{u} \mapsto \widetilde{v}$ and $\widetilde{e_i} \mapsto \widetilde{f_i}$ for all $i$). This is by construction an orthogonal linear map, and thus will have an orthogonal matricial representation in the canonical basis*. Note also that since $A\widetilde{u}=\widetilde{v}$ and $A$ is linear, we have that 
$$A(u)=A(\Vert u\Vert \cdot\widetilde{u})=\Vert u \Vert \cdot \widetilde{v}=\Vert v \Vert \cdot \widetilde{v}=v.$$

As a sidenote, note that such a matrix will depend on the initial bases you take.

*Just to be extremely clear, since you explicitly say in the comments that you are dealing with the definition that $A^TA=AA^T=I$, note that this is equivalent to asking that the collumn vectors of the matrix are orthonormal. The collumn vectors in the canonical basis are precisely $A\cdot E_i$, where $\{E_i\}$ is the canonical basis. Therefore, we must show that 
$$\langle A E_i,A E_j \rangle=\delta_{i,j}.$$
We will prove more generally that $\langle Av, Aw \rangle=\langle v,w\rangle$ (which is usually the definition of an orthogonal map). To see this, note that (letting $\widetilde{e_1}:=\widetilde{u}$ and $\widetilde{v_1}:=\widetilde{v}$).
\begin{align*}
\langle Av,Aw \rangle&= \langle A\left(\sum c_i\widetilde{e_i}\right),A\left(\sum d_j\widetilde{e_j}\right) \rangle \\
&=\langle \sum c_iA\widetilde{e_i},\sum d_jA\widetilde{e_j} \rangle \\
&=\langle \sum c_i\widetilde{f_i},\sum d_j\widetilde{f_j} \rangle \\
&=\sum c_id_i \\
&=\langle \sum c_i\widetilde{e_i},\sum d_j\widetilde{e_j} \rangle \\
&=\langle v, w \rangle.
\end{align*}
Another argument could be to use the above fact that $\langle Av,Aw\rangle=\langle v, w \rangle$ for all $v,w$ to conclude that $\langle A^TA v,w \rangle=\langle v, w\rangle$ for all $v,w$, and thus $\langle (A^TA-I)v,w \rangle=0$ for all $v,w$. Fixing any $v$ and taking $w:=(A^TA-I)v$, we have that $\Vert (A^TA-I)v\Vert^2=0$. Thus, $A^TA-I=0$, and then $A^TA=I$ (analogously, you have that $AA^T=I$).

Comment: What if I want the determinant of the matrix to be 1 ?? How should I change the matrix such that only sign of the determinant changes  not the action of the matrix @AloizioMacedo

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that $u\ne v$, a reflection in the hyperplane that bisects $u$ and $v$ will do the trick. This hyperplane is normal to $u-v$ and passes through the origin. Using [a well-known formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)#Reflection_through_a_hyperplane_in_n_dimensions) for this reflection, we get $$A = I - 2{(u-v)(u-v)^T \over (u-v)^T(u-v)}.$$ It’s easy to verify that $A=A^T$ and that $A^TA = A^2 = I$, so this matrix is indeed orthogonal. With a bit more work you can also verify that $Au=v$.