# Tangent basis to Ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, tangent-spaces, ellipsoids

I have an ellipsoid centered at $0$ (the contour of a Gaussian distribution centered at $0$ with covariance matrix $\Sigma=\Lambda^{-1}$)
$$
x^\top \Lambda x = \gamma
$$
and I know that the gradient at a point is given by
$$
g(x) = -\Lambda x
$$
Is there an expression for the tangent at a point? All I know is that $t(x)^\top g(x) = 0$.

In practice the tangent plane will be a hyperplane so there will be many vectors to choose from. However, I am looking for a tangent basis

Comment: Not that matters, but the ellipsoid stems from having a multivariate Gaussian distribution 
$$
\pi(x) = (2\pi)^{-n/2}|\Sigma|^{-1/2}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}x^\top \Sigma^{-1}x\right\}
$$
and considering the $z$-contour of it, say
$$
x^\top \Sigma^{-1} x = -n\log(2\pi) + \log|\Sigma| -2\log z =:\gamma
$$
Since the log-density is 
$$
\log\pi(x) = -\frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi) -\frac{1}{2}\log|\Sigma| -\frac{1}{2}x^\top \Sigma^{-1} x
$$
the gradient is simply 
$$
g(x) = \nabla_x \log \pi(x) = - \Sigma^{-1} x
$$

Comment: All I know is that we must have $t(x)\perp g(x)$ for any $x$ on the ellipsoid. Therefore we must have 
$$
- t(x)^\top \Lambda x = 0
$$

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for. For each fix $x$, you can find a basis of the tangent using just linear algebra. On the other hand, I doubt if there is any "best" choice of basis.

Comment: For example in 3D you immediately get that the equation for the tangent hyperplane at the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ on the ellipsoid is given by
$$(x_0,y_0,z_0)\Lambda (x,y,z)^T=\gamma.$$ The same in higher dimensions. Finding a basis is a bit inconvenient because one of the coordinates may be zero, and we cannot divide by that. In other words, there are exceptional points on the ellipsoid like "the equator" in 3D where we cannot divide by the $z$-coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand is that you want to obtain a basis for the hyperplane tangent to the ellipse in systematic way. The hyperplane equation is
$$
p^Tg(x) = 0
$$
as you already obtained, where any vector $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ complying with this equation will be tangent at the ellipse for that $x$. This reduces to the question:

**If I have a plane equation $p^Ta=0$ with $\|a\|=1$,  how can I find a basis for this subspace in the most general case?**

This can be applied to your case by picking the $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ of interest and using the  procedure I provide in the following with $a=g(x)/\|g(x)\|$.

---

The normal of the plane is $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$. All vectors in the plane are orthogonal to $a$ since $p^Ta = 0$. In the following we will obtain an orthogonal basis for the plane. First, denote with $e_1,\dots,e_n$ the standard orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e. the columns of the $n\times n$ identity matrix). These comply $e_i^Te_j = 0$ if $i\neq j$ and $e_i^Te_i = 1$.

Now, lets study the following transformation:
$$
A = I - 2\frac{(a - e_n)(a-e_n)^T}{(a-e_n)^T(a-e_n)}
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. A straightforward computation shows that $A = A^T$ and $A^TA=AA = I$. Hence, $A$ is an orthogonal matrix. Now, lets compute $Aa$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Aa&=a- 2\frac{(a - e_n)(a-e_n)^T}{(a-e_n)^T(a-e_n)}a\\
&= a-(a-e_n)\frac{2(a^Ta-e_n^Ta)}{a^Ta-2a^Te_n+e_n^Te_n}\\
& = a - (a-e_n)\frac{2(1-e_n^Ta)}{2-2e_n^Ta} = e_n
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus, $Aa = e_n$ means $a = Ae_n$ since $AA = I$. Hence, $A$ is a matrix that aligns the plane of interest to the "ground" plane orthogonal to $e_n$. This "ground" plane has basis $e_1,\dots,e_{n-1}$ and since $A$ is non-singular we can move between both planes with no problem. If you are interested in how I computed this matrix, it is a reflection over the bisecting plane between $e_n$ and $a$ as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2598812/423711).

Now, lets look at how the basis $e_1,\dots,e_{n-1}$ looks in the original space:
$$
\begin{aligned}
b_1 &= Ae_1\\
&\vdots\\
b_{n-1}&=Ae_{n-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

and verify the desired properties for the vectors $b_1,\dots,b_{n-1}$:

- All $b_1,\dots,b_{n-1}$ belong to the plane $p^Ta = 0$: We check this by computing $b_i^Ta=0$ for any $i=1,\dots,n-1$.
  $$
  b_i^Ta = \left(Ae_i\right)^T\left(Ae_n\right) = e_i^T(AA)e_n = e_i^Te_n = 0
  $$
  since $i\neq n$ and $AA=I, A=A^T$.
- $\{b_1,\dots,b_{n-1}\}$ is a basis: We check this by showing that these are $n-1$ independent vectors. This follows simply by noticing that $b_i,b_j$ are orthogonal for $i\neq j$ by a similar argument as before:
  $$
  b_i^Tb_j = \left(Ae_i\right)^T\left(Ab_j\right) = e_i^T(AA)b_j = e_i^Tb_j = 0
  $$
- **Small technical detail**: this cannot work if $a = e_n$ since $A$ would not be defined. However, you can pick any other $e_i$ with $i\neq n$ without loss of generality for that matter.

---

**Summary**

- You have $g(x)$ as the tangent vector of the hyperellipse, and define $\hat{g}(x) = g(x)/\|g(x)\|$.
- You define the matrix
  $$
  A(x) = I - 2\frac{(\hat{g}(x) - e_n)(\hat{g}(x)-e_n)^T}{(\hat{g}(x)-e_n)^T(\hat{g}(x)-e_n)}
  $$
- You compute the vectors $t_1(x),\dots,t_{n-1}(x)$ as:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  t_1(x) &= A(x)e_1\\
  &\vdots\\
  t_{n-1}(x)&=A(x)e_{n-1}
  \end{aligned}
  $$
- Then, $\{t_1(x),\dots,t_{n-1}(x)\}$ is an orthogonal basis for the tangent plane of your hyper-ellipse at the point $x$.
- Last comment: note that this is not the only basis for the tangent plane.

I hope that I did not messed up anywhere and this is correct, please check. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, not sure why someone downvoted it. I will have a thorough look in the next few days!

Comment: Maybe because this doesn't work if $g(x)=e_n$. Still, I gave a work around. Or maybe I wasn't formal enough. Anyway, I was just trying to help. Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "Is there an expression for the tangent at a point?"

**Answer:** Let $k$ be the real numbers. If your ellipsoid $E$ is given as the zero set of the following polynomial

$$F(x_1,..,x_n):=a_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2+\cdots + a_nx_n^2-a_{n+1}$$

with $a_i>0$ real numbers, it follows the tangent hyperplane $T_p(E)$ to $E$ at a point $p:=(p_1,..,p_n)$ is the zero set of the following linear polynomial:

$$H_p(E)(x_1,..,x_n):=a_1p_1(x_1-p_1)+\cdots + a_np_n(x_n-p_n).$$

Hence $T_p(E)$ is the set of points $q:=(q_1,..,q_n)\in k^n$ with $H_p(E)(q_1,..,q_n)=0$.

**Note:** A general formula for the (embedded) tangent plane $T_p(X)$ at the (smooth) hypersurface $X:=V(F)$ where $F(x_1,..,x_n)$ is a polynomial, is given by

$$h_p(E):=\frac{\partial F}{\partial_{x_1}}(p)(x_1-p_1)+ \cdots \frac{\partial F}{\partial_{x_n}}(p)(x_n-p_n)=0.$$

By

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial_{x_i}}(p)$$

I mean the partial derivative of $F$ wrto the $x_i$-variable, evaluated at the point $p$. The embedded tangent space $T_p(E)$ is not a vector subspace of $k^n$.